# Edit dashboard based on user ID

Tags: users, dashboard

Is there a way to edit the dashboard based on the user ID? I know this is relatively straight forward when targeting a user role, but how about ID?

For a working example, something along the lines of changing the admin menu background color for the user ID of 7.

Comment: Why not to give that user a specific role?

Comment: Would this allow the super admin 'role' I understand its not a role it's based on the admin role with extras. If so, If I gave them the role super admin v2 for example how would I add superadmin capabilities?

Comment: depends on how you creat the role. I am not using much this kind of plugins but AFAIK there should not be any problem to use a plugin and assign whatever capabilities that you want to any role.